# FME: How can I use File Copy Writer to periodically copy new data within my project folders to a server?

Tags: fme-form, data-backup, writers

All I want to do is copy a set of folders (and sub-folders) under a 'Projects' master folder on my laptop to the server. I want to automate this so it runs every hour or two and only copies new files to the server (so no overwrite).

Under the 'Projects' folder I have named project folders, i.e. 'Project A', 'Project B' etc.

The folder structure for each project is identical so they each have 'Incoming', 'Outgoing', 'Working' etc. and several sub-folders folders. Some are empty and some contain data. As project evolve, the standard set of folders gets populated with data and workflows.

The problem I have is that I can't seem to get file copy writer to copy this structure correctly. Data gets duplicated and the folder structure is lost. It also duplicates file gdbs at the root level of the destination directory and copyies ou the contents of gdb folders. Additionally it moves sub-folders to the root level so I end up with a mess...and duplicate data!

Should I run a workspace caller on each folder? Don't want a two step process so was hoping there was a way around using that approach.

[image: Path parameters]
[image: Writer(filecopy) parameters]

[[image: Workbench][2]]

Comment: Do you have a network drive? This would make it much more efficient. Our FME Servers runs with a network account rather than local account, this gives it access to the network drive.

Comment: @Mapperz, yes, the example shows me copying to my c:\temp as a test but I have also tested it copying to a server. Unfortunately I cannot get it to obey the folder structures for each project regardless of where I copy to.

Comment: try the Feature Reader route https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/78732/directory-and-file-pathnames-reader-equivalent-for.html

Comment: I'm still not getting consistent copying of the folder structure. In theory this should be easiest workbench to construct as there aren't any format changes. I have python script that does this perfectly but I wanted to use FME so that I can share it with my team as not everyone is able to read the code and deploy the script.